# How do I use link_to_remote to pass then render a partial in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to-remote

I want to create several link_to_remote links that are campaign names:

```
<% @campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
<!--link_to_remote(name, options = {}, html_options = nil)-->
   <%= link_to_remote(campaign, :update => "campaign_todo",
                                :url => %>    
<% end %>
```

I want the output to update on the page to render a partial, which runs a loop through the values associated with the campaign.

The API docs says this will render a partial, but I'm not clear where the name of the :partial template is passed in, either here or in the controller

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller would render the partial, according to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002174).

> Usually, the result would be a partial prepared by the controller with render :partial.

Answer (score 0):

of course in the controller. Here you create an AJAX snippet that will pull an **url** you specify from your controller.

generated javascript has no access to any partials b/c it runs on client PC.

and controller decides WHAT to respond to this request. it can render a partial, a template, a text, or anything.